# の before 後, mandatory or not?

Tags: grammar

In a textbook I saw this sentence talking about drugs:

> 一日に二回朝ご飯と晩ご飯後に飲んでください。

Is there a missing "の" between 晩ご飯 and 後? Is it ok to remove this particle in casual speech?

Comment: on note about the reading : in the textbook 後 was with あと furigana.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the following are possible combinations.

- Noun + [後]{ご}  　e.g. [食事後]{しょくじご}
- Noun + の[後]{あと}　e.g. 食事の[後]{あと}
- Verb phrase + [後]{あと}　e.g. 食事した[後]{あと}

it depends on each word which of 後 and の後 sounds more natural. 食事後/食事の後 sound equally natural to me, but 晩ご飯[後]{ご} does not sound quite idiomatic, at least less so than 夕食[後]{ご}.

Roughly speaking, it should be more common to use [後]{ご} with 漢語 and の[後]{あと} with 和語 while there are many that can go with both (like 食事). Also due to this nature, [後]{ご} sounds more formal (and thus appropriate for an instruction of medicine).

Comment: じゃ、「晩ご飯」は和語だから、「ばんごはんご」より「ばんごはんあと」って読みたくなりますよね。　・・・　いや、これは「晩ご飯**の**後」の「の」が抜けてしまった（書き間違えた）だけと考えた方がいいのでしょうか？

Comment: @Chocolate 自分は少なくとも違和感ありますね、間違いとまで言えるかは微妙だと思いますが。たぶん多くの場合は「一日二回、朝晩食後に服用」とかなのでは。やわらかい文章にしようとして中途半端になったとか・・？

Comment: @Chocolate Is 晩ご飯 not considered 漢語 seeing as ばん, ご, and はん are on'yomi readings?

Comment: ああっ、「ごはん」って、和語じゃないんだ！？和語は・・・「めし」か！！

Comment: In either case, it doesn't necessarily mean that ばんごはんご would be natural (as a non-native, I can't say), because there are certainly exceptions to matching 漢語 with on'yomi prefixes and suffixes.

Comment: If we see cross-kanji consistency in pronunciation, isn't that a sure sign it's 漢語? ご飯{はん}, 反対{はんたい}, 平板{へいばん}, 一版{いっぱん}

Comment: I would say 食事の後 or 食後. I guess 食事 is not considered 漢語 enough. It takes お for a prefix.

Comment: Sorry to make the discussion more complex. My issue is that in the textbook where I got this sentence, 後 was with あと furigana. That's why I don't understand there is no の to connect this with the Noun 晩ご飯.

Comment: @Poulp Then I think it's a typo as Chocolate suggested. In casual speech, ごはんあと is not entirely impossible, though.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are right, the grammar rule states that if we are using a noun we must add　の. I bet that is a kind of abreviation of that.

https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%A7-%E3%81%82%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7-ato-de-meaning/

Comment: That page is about あと, but this should be the suffix ご.